# How to get this specific responsive nav?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I am working on a project and I am trying to achieve this responsive navigation
from 
http://www.rvamedia.com/wordpress/

I want the logo to be on top of the responsive nav icon and the drop down to be like so (smooth and what not).
I also want to know the basic way of having the nav displayed the way it is when scaled down to mobile version

The difference I am trying to achieve however is that my desktop navigation will be a centered nav with a logo in the middle, and I want to know how to go from that to the mobile version that I mentioned above

I hope I am being specific and thanks for viewing my question!

My navigation for desktop is as follows

```
       <nav class="nav">
        <ul>
                <li>Home </li>
                <li>About </li>
                <li>Portfolio </li>
                <li>Contact </li>
        </ul>
       </nav>
    <a class="logo" href="http://www.website.com"></a>
```

And CSS

```
  nav li{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 40px 30px 40px 0;
  }

  nav li:nth-child(2) {
  padding-right: 80px;
  }

  nav li:nth-child(3) {
  padding-left: 80px;
  }

  .logo {
  background: url(logo.png) 50% 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: 32px 59px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 59px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 460px;
  }
```

(if there is a better way of doing the center I'm all ears! )

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like [this](http://codepen.io/thesublimeobject/pen/wKach) for the first half. And then for the second half, I would use some kind of media query to hide the nav and then use [this](http://slicknav.com/) plugin. I've used it before and it was pretty easy to work with.  You just need a good handle on media queries and a little jQuery and you should be able to achieve that nav without much problem.

```
<header>
<a class="logo" href="http://www.website.com">Logo</a>
<nav class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Home </li>
    <li>About </li>
    <li>Portfolio </li>
    <li>Contact </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</header>

header {
  width: 100%;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  display: block;
}

header:before, header:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: table;
}

header:after {
  clear: both;
}

nav.nav {
  width: 75%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

ul {
  text-align: right;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

a.logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  a.logo, nav.nav {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 1em;
    text-align: center;
  }
  ul {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```